# Already have a DOI number but can't find it

Tags: doi, acm

My paper was accepted and it was given a DOI, but I can't find yet.
It seems the conference didn't upload the papers for the ACM digital library yet.

1. Is it normal?
2. How long does it take to upload a conference paper to the ACM DL?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *can't find yet?* Via the DOI, on the publisher’s page or something else?

Comment: Can't find the document by the DOI number at http://www.doi.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ACM normally publishes its conference proceedings just before the conference begins.  The default used to be **immediately** before the conference begins, but at least some ACM conferences have proceedings available a week in advance.

If you want to double-check (especially if the conference has already happened), you should ask the program committee chair.

Comment: Thanks @JeffE. I'm contacting the program committee chair to see what happened.

Comment: I contact the comittee and they will send the proceedings to ACM DL next week.

Comment: Worth noting that the various systems involved can introduce delays of a day or so.